# Webstorm Context Folder always included on url path?

Tags: webstorm

Based on my understanding WebStorm has the concept of context Root ( basically the root of your project for source purposes)  and Resource Roots folder(s) from which web requests can be resolved relative to.

I've got a project structure like

```
Projects (Context Root)
      |
      MyProject  (ResourceRoot)
         |--- html
         |----css
         |----images
```

I'd like to access my html files like so http://localhost:34343/html/index.html

however that's not possible. The only way I can access files is when the 'Projects' context root forms part of my url.  e.g http://localhost:34343/**Projects**/html/index.html

(note that the resourceroot seems to be working to some extent as a I can omit the 'MyProject' part of the path.

I've got some css with absolute references that want to access /images which break when the context root has to be included.   As far as I can tell moving the Context root 'down' a level isn't going to help as it will require 'MyProject' on  the path.

I'm guessing I can probably force it to use something like apache where I can get more control of url resolution, but Ideally I'd use the built in server from the IDE.

Comment: `Projects` in your case is a PROJECT_NAME. The other URL that is possible to use is `http://PROJECT_NAME:63342/...`. Project name is required in URL in order for built-in web server to identify what files to serve (same as Host/Server name in web server configs).

Comment: requiring the name makes sense I guess in context of multiple projects (although I'd have through separate server ports would be better) .  I'm curious about the http://PROJECT_NAME:63342/ syntax.   I presume I've got to set up a localhost alias in my hosts file to do this ?  will webstorm recognise the project_name automatically?

Comment: nevermind, gave it a try and it works..  wanna upgrade your comment to an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http://localhost:63342/html/index.html` -- *you cannot have this kind of URL with built-in web server* .. as IDE does not know what project to serve (as it works for ALL your projects a not only currently opened).

When built-in web server is in use, the URL has to have some hint (`PROJECT_NAME`) that would tell what project to serve (where to take files from).

Built-in web server supports 2 kind of URLs (both of them will serve the same file):

```
http://localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/index.html
http://PROJECT_NAME:63342/index.html
```

If you happy with 2nd URL, then you will have to do these steps:

1. Create Deployment entry (`Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Deployment`) and mark it as Default for this project. The URL defined there (`http://PROJECT_NAME:63342/`) will be used when opening pages from within IDE.

   This is required if you want to use `Open in Browser` functionality, otherwise you may safely skip it.
2. In your `hosts` file (or your local DNS server, if you have one) define an entry that would point `PROJECT_NAME` to your IP. For example (for `hosts` file): `127.0.0.1 PROJECT_NAME`.

Comment: What is the PROJECT_NAME ? i have c:\xampp\htdocs\...

Comment: @CristianE. `PROJECT_NAME` is your project name in your WebStorm. AFAIK this functionality may have been removed now. I suggest using a proper web server (e.g. Apache from your XAMPP) to serve your files if you need such setup.