# how to configure application root path in intellij for web browser preview

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I am working on an Angular application, it is a single page application hosted on say `src/main/webapp/index.html`

with script references like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

The script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

is physically located at `src/main/webapp/vendors/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js`

When I open browser preview in browser preview in chrome it launches the url

```
http://localhost:63342/myApp/main/webapp/play.html
```

and then browser tries to load the script from

```
http://localhost:63342/vendors/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js
```

which is basically sitting at

```
http://localhost:63342/myApp/main/webapp/vendors/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js
```

I would like to know if there is a way set the application root path for intellij config.

Thanks in advance. :)

PS: What is usual way js/html/css devs use for quick code and test cycles?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular .. but how it would work on real site? I mean this: "is physically located at `src/main/webapp/vendors/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js`" In any case: try marking `src/main/webapp/` as Resource Root.

Comment: As for getting rid `/myApp` from URL -- the only alternative is to use `http://myApp:63342/` kind of URL instead of `http://localhost:63342/myApp/` (as IDE still needs to know what project to serve; just like any proper web server does) -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/24908091/783119 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/32990633/783119