# WebStorm - How to remove the project folder form the URL?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I view an AngularJs project in my browser using WebStorm (Version 2016.1.3). It show a URL like below.

```
http://localhost:63342/project-folder-name/index.html
```

This affects my AngularJS routes as I have to change my base tag to `<base href="project-folder-name/">`

When I want to push to production, I have to then change it again to `<base href="/">`, which is pretty tedious.

I have researched this and everything seem to point at `Preferences -> Directories -> Mark Folder as Resource Root`. However, this doesn't seem to do anything.

Normally on Nginx I would just set a `root /html/project-folder-name` under my location block, however I am sure this has come up before and there is an option to tick that I am missing.

Question: How do I remove the project folder name from the URL.

Comment: 1) It's not "project-folder-name" but actually a "project-name". You can rename the project while having folder name unchanged -- IDE will use "project-name" for that  2) You cannot fully remove it -- IDE still needs to know what project to serve (similar to domain name in real world). Workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32990633/783119

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for the work around. Its pretty poor for an "JS" IDE not not support this functionality. I think I might have to go back to sublime.

Comment: 1) Which functionality? IDE needs to know what project to serve. In real world/internet the domain name does this job. How this supposed to work here without such info if every project will be served **on the same port**? Please share your insights. 2) You are free to use your own proper web server Apache/nginx/IIS/etc -- just configure IDE for that (the deployment entry).

Comment: @LazyOne Having to manually configure your own Web Server and add entries to ones host file doesn't seem like something that I should be doing for a paid application. As angularJS and ngRoutes are a popular choice, I would have thought the smart people at JetBrain would have a simple solution. Either way, I appreciate your comments.

Comment: If you have some good ideas on how to make this configuration-free or at least to simplify this process -- please file a ticket at their [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB) -- I would like to read this as well. Surely, adding "only one project can be served at a time" restriction can solve this issue.. but in real world people also work on multiple projects simultaneously (or multiple aspects of the same site done in sep projects) where you *must have* some marker which can be used to identify what project/files to serve, esp when web server uses *single port number*.